# c# Reading structs from memory that contain arrays

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct

I am having trouble converting this struct into c#. my attempt works for the most part. Is there a way of declaring it that will work out how many WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS to create, like WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS[dwNumberOfPhys]?

```
typedef struct _WLAN_STATISTICS {
  ULONGLONG                 ullFourWayHandshakeFailures;
  ULONGLONG                 ullTKIPCounterMeasuresInvoked;
  ULONGLONG                 ullReserved;
  WLAN_MAC_FRAME_STATISTICS MacUcastCounters;
  WLAN_MAC_FRAME_STATISTICS MacMcastCounters;
  DWORD                     dwNumberOfPhys;
  WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS PhyCounters[1];
} WLAN_STATISTICS, *PWLAN_STATISTICS;
```

What I have so far:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WLAN_STATISTICS {
    public ulong ullFourWayHandshakeFailures;
    public ulong ullTKIPCounterMeasuresInvoked;
    public ulong ullReserved;
    public WLAN_MAC_FRAME_STATISTICS MacUcastCounters;
    public WLAN_MAC_FRAME_STATISTICS MacMcastCounters;
    public int dwNumberOfPhys;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS[] PhyCounters;
}
```

The SizeConst should really be equal to dwNumberOfPhys and i'm unsure how best to do this.

I'm using Marshal.PtrToStructure to get the data into the structure.

I guess what i'm asking is: is there a nice way to declare this so that the array is automatically the correct size or do i need to read this as a byte array and manage the struct contents myself?

Comment: You could just declare the array to be big enough for all eventualities.

Comment: i've tried SizeConst=8 which does seem to work. I've has AccessViolation exceptions once or twice though

Comment: I don't know how you are using it -- but do you set dwNumberOfPhys?

Comment: the structure is read from a pointer, so dwNumberOfPhys is always set, typically to 3 or 4

Comment: presumably PhyCounters can get filled up to that value?

Comment: yes, the PhyCounters is always at least one, but is normally more, here's a link to the structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: When using these sorts of structures you normally call the Winapi and it tells you how many PhyCounters are to be expected. You then allocate the space and pass the structure in.